# Java FX ComboBoxTableCell Show In Every Cell

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I've got a table which has a combo cell which you can select a value from for each row entry. The problem is, the drop down list only shows when the cell is being edited, and I would like it to show on every row at all times. Is this possible and if so, how?

[image]

```
    TableColumn<Product, String> actionsCol = new TableColumn<Product, String>("Exception Reason");
    actionsCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("exceptionReason"));
    actionsCol.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(exceptionReasons));
    actionsCol.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Product, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<Product, String> t) {
                    ((Product) t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setExceptionReason(t.getNewValue());
                };
    });
    actionsCol.setEditable(true);
```

Comment: You'll need to post your code that produces this result here.

Comment: @ManoDestra - Question updated with column code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by implementing your own table cell (and setting a cell factory to instantiate it):

```
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableWithComboBoxExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Item> table = new TableView<>();

        TableColumn<Item, String> itemCol = new TableColumn<>("Item");
        itemCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().nameProperty());

        TableColumn<Item, Reason> reasonCol = new TableColumn<>("Reason");
        reasonCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().importanceProperty());

        reasonCol.setCellFactory(tc -> {
            ComboBox<Reason> combo = new ComboBox<>();
            combo.getItems().addAll(Reason.values());
            TableCell<Item, Reason> cell = new TableCell<Item, Reason>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(Reason reason, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(reason, empty);
                    if (empty) {
                        setGraphic(null);
                    } else {
                        combo.setValue(reason);
                        setGraphic(combo);
                    }
                }
            };
            combo.setOnAction(e -> 
                table.getItems().get(cell.getIndex()).setImportance(combo.getValue()));
            return cell ;
        });

        table.getColumns().add(itemCol);
        table.getColumns().add(reasonCol);

        Random rng = new Random();
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 100 ; i++) {
            table.getItems().add(new Item("Item "+i, Reason.values()[rng.nextInt(Reason.values().length)]));
        }

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(table));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public enum Reason { DATA_NOT_OBTAINABLE, IM_JUST_PLAIN_LAZY, I_CANT_BE_BOTHERED }

    public static class Item {
        private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final ObjectProperty<Reason> importance = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

        public Item(String name, Reason importance) {
            setName(name);
            setImportance(importance);
        }

        public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return this.name;
        }


        public final String getName() {
            return this.nameProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setName(final String name) {
            this.nameProperty().set(name);
        }


        public final ObjectProperty<Reason> importanceProperty() {
            return this.importance;
        }


        public final Reason getImportance() {
            return this.importanceProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setImportance(final Reason importance) {
            this.importanceProperty().set(importance);
        }



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I presume the setGraphic(combo) method is responsible for showing the combo box, so if the reason was empty, I could still have it show by using setGraphic(combo)?

Comment: What do you mean by "if the reason was empty?". Do you mean if `reason==null`? In that case the code above would still show the combo box, but with nothing selected.

Comment: Thanks @James_D. Yes, by empty I meant null. Your solution has worked for my scenario. Many Thanks